# Entity FrameWork 7(beta 4) migrations error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, visual-studio-2015

Who else is getting this error from the Package Manager console when he/she runs the 'Add-Migration Blah' command

```
add-migration : The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of 
a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the     path is correct 
and try again.
```

I have included the EntityFramework.Commands dependency(for beta4)

NEW EDIT: 
This is more like an advice. Before you run the kpm commands, you should go to the package manager settings and untick the "api.nuget.org". If not you will keep getting the 400 error

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678792/ef-data-migrations-does-not-work-after-close-project and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567657/update-database-error-nuget-package-entityframework-sqlmigrations

Comment: @Bharathi none of those solutions worked sadly

Comment: Have you tried  "k ef migration add" ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385736/ef7-commands-do-not-work-in-vs2015-ctp-6

Comment: Yes I just did. But I had to run the kpm restore command first. I will update the question with a screenshot of the error I got from running the kpm restore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone getting the problem **at the time of writing**, dont use k. Use dnx instead. I used that and it worked for me.

dnx . ef migration add initial was the command that worked.

Use this as a guide to installing dnx
https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Version-Manager